# Discord.js Is there a way to make a bot show the content of a website?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So, i wanted to create a command for my bot, (its a bot for me and my schoolmates) and i want to make it show a webpage when i execute the command. The reason why is so i can see my school schedule for the day, please tell me if this is possible and if it is how to make it. Have a good day all!

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm called ***pageres*** that is able to take a screenshot of a website.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pageres

Comment: Hey! How can i make a code to work with that?

Comment: How can i make a code to work with pageres??

Comment: You were linked to the package, and the package will provide documentation.

Comment: @Elitezen Well, do you know how to login to a webpage so i can see it.

Comment: Click on the link and read the contents. There's a description, example and documentation section. Everything you will need is being given, it's up to you to read up

Comment: Well, they don't mention anything about discord and stuff.

Comment: Discord.JS and Pageres are both NPM modules. Simply integrate them together.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the bot scrape the site for stuff you are following maybe using puppeteer package or some sort of scraping package for discord js request-promise-native, Unirest, Cheerio, Puppeteer. Osmosis.